# SharpDevelop Drag-and-Drop a external file to a project as a link

Tags: file, ide, drag-and-drop, sharpdevelop

In #develop (SharpDevelop IDE)

I can add a file to a project as a link via :
Right click in the project -> Add -> Existing item -> Add as link

but how can I do this via drag-and-drop...
I've tryed the usual stuff, pressing Shift or Ctrl or Alt + drag-an-drop file but nothing seems to work... :(

Help need..

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported in SharpDevelop. OUt of interest I checked Visual Studio and it looks like Visual Studio 2010 does not support this but Visual Studio 2012 does if you hold Ctrl+Shift when you drop the files.

Looking at the [SharpDevelop source code](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/blob/master/src/Main/Base/Project/Src/Gui/Pads/ProjectBrowser/TreeNodes/DirectoryNode.cs#L824) it only copies the files or directory dropped onto the Projects window.

Comment: Yes,,, that is what I've found too... I use SharpDevelop in places where I do not have VisualStudio and this type of feature sometimes is need...